# Ruby on Rails Parameter has been sent to Controller but hasn't saved in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I sent the parameter from Postman. Parameters are successfully sent to Server. but Controller doesn't save it into Database.

I tried to make initializer in User.rb but it doesn't works with initializer "Parameter is missed. given 1, expected 3" error message.

So I erased initializer and Server can receive the parameters well but cannot save in database.

[image]

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  
  attr_accessor :email, :pwd, :usertype  

=begin  
 def initialize(email, pwd, usertype) @email=email, @pwd=pwd, @usertype=usertype end=end  

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i  
  validates :email, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false},  
  format: {with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX}, length: {minimum:3, maximum:50}  

  validates :pwd, presence: true, length: {minimum:3, maximum:25}  

  has_many :bookings  


end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController  
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]  

  # GET /users  
 # GET /users.json  def index  
  @users = User.all  
  end  

  # GET /users/1  
 # GET /users/1.json  def show  
  end  

  # POST /users  
 # POST /users.json  def create  
  @user = User.new(user_params)  

    if @user.save  
      render :show, status: :created, location: @user  
  else  
  render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity  
  end  
 end  
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1  
 # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json  def update  
  if @user.update(user_params)  
      render :show, status: :ok, location: @user  
  else  
  render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity  
  end  
 end  
  # DELETE /users/1  
 # DELETE /users/1.json  def destroy  
  @user.destroy  
  end  

  private  
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.  
  def set_user  
  @user = User.find(params[:id])  
    end  

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.  
  def user_params  
  params.require(:user).permit(:email, :pwd, :usertype)  
      # params.permit!  
  end  
end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  resources :bookings  
  resources :users  
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html  
  #  

end
```

Server message

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-12-27 21:53:13 +0900
   (2.6ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
  �넶 C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
   (1.0ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
  �넶 C:/Ruby25-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.2/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
Processing by UsersController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"email"=>"admin2@namver.com", "pwd"=>"Reza Adha", "usertype"=>"Hamonangan", "user"=>{"email"=>"admin2@namver.com", "pwd"=>"Reza Adha", "usertype"=>"Hamonangan"}}
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  �넶 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20
  User Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`email` = 'admin2@namver.com' LIMIT 1
  �넶 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20
  User Create (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO `users` (`created_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2018-12-27 12:53:13', '2018-12-27 12:53:13')
  �넶 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20
   (60.1ms)  COMMIT
  �넶 app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20
  Rendering users/show.json.jbuilder
  Rendered users/_user.json.jbuilder (0.8ms)
  Rendered users/show.json.jbuilder (280.3ms)
Completed 201 Created in 1431ms (Views: 1299.2ms | ActiveRecord: 102.5ms)
```

As you can see, server received paramater well. but Controller insert only created_at, updated_at  date column.

[image]

Comment: Are you really going to store the password in plain text into your database?

Comment: Why do you have those `attr_accessor` and `initialize` methods in the model? Rails should already dynamically define methods relating to table column names; I believe the issue is that you're overriding them with these custom ones that "do nothing". in terms of database transactions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove this line

```
attr_accessor :email, :pwd, :usertype
```

from your `User` class.

The setter and getter methods generated by `attr_accessor` override the getter and setter methods that are created by Rails automatically.

And – for security reasons – please do not store passwords in plaintext into your database. I suggest reading about [`has_secure_password`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: Thanks!! It works!!  Also thanks for advise in password